# Hidden rocks of func3(func1(), func2())?

Tags: c

Is there any problem with using another function call as a function parameter in C?

```
int foo1(int a){/*does something */ return a;}
int foo2(int b){/*does something */ return b;}
int foo3(int a, int b){return a+b;} 

int result = foo3(foo1(1),foo2(2)); /*result is 3 */
```

Comment: No, there is no..... It is very common :)

Comment: the only issue is that the order of evaluation of function arguments is **unspecified**. It's not a issue as long as the side effects of the functions are not observable

Comment: BTW [result is 3](https://ideone.com/Zp0FFK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on [tstanisl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989451/tstanisl)'s comment

```
int foo1(int a) { puts("ONE"); return a++; }
int foo2(int b) { puts("TWO"); return b++; }
int foo3(int a, int b) { return a+b; } 

int result = foo3(foo1(1),foo2(2));
```

There is no specific order for the prints. Any of

```
ONE                                     TWO
TWO                                     ONE
```

is possible. Can even change next time you recompile (or run) your executable!

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with the code in your question.

That code *looks* very much like it's intended to demonstrate a potential problem with calls like `foo3(foo1(1),foo2(2))`, but it fails to do so.

For example:

```
int foo1(int a){return a++;}
```

The expression `a++` has a side effect, but one that's irrelevant. The parameter `a` is a local variable, and it ceases to exist when the function returns. It might as well be just `return a;` (except for possible undefined behavior if the increment overflows).

This:

```
int n = 42;
int func(int param) { return param++; }
```

returns the value 42 and does not affect the value of `n`. The `++` applies to a copy of `n`, not to `n` itself. Function arguments in C are passed by value.

The potential problem with that kind of call is that the order of the evaluation of the arguments is unspecified. The calls `foo1(1)` and `foo2(2)` have no side effects that are visible to the caller, but a call like `foo3(a++, a++)` would, and could yield different results depending on the unspecified order in which the arguments are evaluated. (I'm not 100% certain whether that case has undefined behavior; it depends on whether there's a *sequence point* between the evaluations of the arguments. But that uncertainty alone is more than enough reason to avoid writing code like that.)